# Geom_vline() wont show on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
> glimpse(mn)
Observations: 63
Variables: 5
$ date   <dttm> 2020-03-06, 2020-03-07, 2020-03-08, 2020-03-09, 2020-0…
$ state  <chr> "Minnesota", "Minnesota", "Minnesota", "Minnesota", "Mi…
$ fips   <dbl> 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27,…
$ cases  <dbl> 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 9, 14, 21, 35, 54, 60, 77, 89, 115, 1…
$ deaths <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1…
> glimpse(events)
Observations: 7
Variables: 2
$ date  <date> 2020-03-06, 2020-03-13, 2020-03-15, 2020-03-16, 2020-03…
$ event <chr> "First Cases Confirmed", "State of emergency Declared", …
```

I created a plot for MN cases

```
mn_plot <- ggplot(mn, aes(x = date, y = cases)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("COVID-19 Cases in Minnesota") +
  xlab("Date(2020)") + 
  ylab("Cases")
```

Wanted to add some important dates, so I did this

```
events <- tribble(
  ~ date, ~ event,
  "2020-03-06", "First Cases Confirmed",
  "2020-03-13", "State of emergency Declared",
  "2020-03-15", "Temporary shut down of schools",
  "2020-03-16", "All non-erssential businesses close",
  "2020-03-21", "First death recorded in MN",
  "2020-04-08", "Stay-at-Home Order Placed",
  "2020-04-30", "Stay-at-Home Order Extended",
) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))
```

Now I want to add the tribble I just made to my plot to show time stamps of when events happened.

```
mn_plot +
  geom_vline(data = events, aes(xintercept = as.numeric(date)), linetype = "dotted")
```

My problem is that the vertical lines will not show up.

Here are the packages I am using:

```
library("readxl")
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of `nm` to make you question reproducible? If it's not too big use `dput(nm)` or provide a sample from `nm`

Comment: You may need to confirm that the format for `date` in `mn` is the same as in `events`. Should  the aes argument in `geom_vline be `aes(xintercept = date)`?

Comment: Sorry, just added a glimpse of the data I have

Comment: Your `date` in `mn` is POSIX.ct perhaps? And your `date` in `events` is `Date`? Try changing your `mn$date` to `Date` and see if that works.

Comment: Agree with @Ben.  I think you have a mismatch in the format of your date in `events` and `mn`.  It should work if they are any of the date formats, but they need to be the same.  I find working with `lubridate` and using `as.Date` is easiest, but that's just me.  Note that after making sure the columns are the same format, you will want to use `xintercept=date`, not `as.numeric()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `mn$date` is a `<dttm>` datetime format (as expressed by `tibbles`) it is equivalent to `POSIXct`: as identified by @Ben's comment; the format includes: year, month, day, hour, minute and second.

Whereas your variable `events$date` is in `<date>` format which includes year, month, day

To get the geom_vline to plot you need both date variables to be in the same date format either date or datetime; the answer goes for datetime.

There's a bit about the  tidyverse take on dates and times in https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html.

By the way if you could include a minimal dataframe or tibble in future questions you would really help anybody who wanted to answer: in this case `mn` made up from random data to provide an answer.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

mn <- tibble(
  date = seq(ymd_hms("2020-03-06 00:00:00"), by = "day", length.out = 63),
  cases = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 14L, 21L, 35L, 
            54L, 60L, 77L, 89L, 115L, 137L, 169L, 235L, 261L, 287L, 346L, 
            398L, 441L, 503L, 576L, 629L, 689L, 742L, 789L, 865L, 935L, 986L, 
            1069L, 1154L, 1242L, 1336L, 1427L, 1621L, 1650L, 1695L, 1809L, 
            1912L, 2071L, 2213L, 2356L, 2470L, 2567L, 2721L, 2942L, 3185L, 
            3446L, 3602L, 3816L, 4181L, 4644L, 5136L, 5730L, 6228L, 6663L, 
            7234L, 7851L, 8579L, 9365L, 10088L))



events <- tribble(
  ~ date, ~ event,
  "2020-03-06", "First Cases Confirmed",
  "2020-03-13", "State of emergency Declared",
  "2020-03-15", "Temporary shut down of schools",
  "2020-03-16", "All non-erssential businesses close",
  "2020-03-21", "First death recorded in MN",
  "2020-04-08", "Stay-at-Home Order Placed",
  "2020-04-30", "Stay-at-Home Order Extended",
) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd_hms(paste0(date, " 00:00:00")))


ggplot(mn, aes(x = date, y = cases)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(data = events, aes(xintercept = date), linetype = "dotted")+
  ggtitle("COVID-19 Cases in Minnesota") +
  xlab("Date(2020)") + 
  ylab("Cases")
```

Which results in:

[image]